# annotating text in ggplot2 with expression bgroup is not working

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following code adds a text annotation of rsquared to a ggplot2 chart

```
ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=hwy, y=cty))+
geom_point()+
annotate("text", x=30, y=30, label="r^2", parse=TRUE)
```

If I run `?plotmath`, the right-hand column, labelled syntax, has many examples of mathematical expressions. If I copy any of these and substitute them for `r^2` in the above example, the output appears as expected. With 2 exceptions:

`group("(",list(a, b),"]")` which produces `Error: unexpected ']'`

and

`bgroup("(",atop(x,y),")")` which produces `Error: unexpected symbol`

I would like to know how to annotate a `ggplot2` chart with the text that group and bgroup are supposed to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! If you use quotes inside quotes, make them single instead of double. That being said, e.g. for the second example of yours

```
ggplot(data=mpg, aes(x=hwy, y=cty))+
    geom_point()+
    annotate("text", x=30, y=30, label="bgroup('(',atop(x,y),')')", parse=TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for this. In retrospect, it makes sense, but I would never have figured it out on my own. I would have up-rated your answer, but don't have the points to do that

Comment: Always a pleasure. Note that you can still accept answers on your questions (the green check mark).